# TFS Build Agent seems to ignore my active solution configuration and builds all projects

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, solution

Requesting a build from TFS, the Build agent seems to ignore the active solution configuration and builds all the projects in our solution. We have excluded certain projects in our solution and TFS build does not seem to honour this.

I have left Items To Build -> Configurations to Build blank so I am led to believe it should build the 'default solution configuration'. This leads me to think the, 'default solution configuration' is different to the, 'active solution configuration'.  Am I correct in this and if so, where do I set this, 'default solution configuration'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have set as an active Build Configuration locally is completely different than the Build configuration on Team Build.  Usually Team Build will build in Release mode.  You need to look at the configuration of the build and see what "flavor" or "flavors" it is configured to build.  If you modify the Build configuration for the flavors set in the Build Configuration, Team build will then build what you want.